# How to solve $\{ x \in \mathbb N_0 \mid x \cdot416 \equiv 1696 \pmod {2208} \}$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, equivalence-relations

How to solve $\{ x \in \mathbb N_0 | x \cdot416 \equiv 1696 \pmod {2208}\}$?

Since $416$ is not invertible in $2208$ I have cancelled everything by $\gcd(416, 2208, 1696)= 32$.

That gives:

$\{ x \in \mathbb N_0 \mid x \cdot13 \equiv53  \pmod {69} \}$.

So I have calculated $13^{-1} $ mod $69 = 16$.

That is the wrong result. The correct answer would be $20$.

Question: What is the way to solve that task?

Comment: Why would you compute $13^{-1}\pmod {53}$?  You need to compute it $\pmod {69}$.

Comment: @lulu, I have corrected my mistake. Unfortunately I am still not able to solve that

Comment: Right...so multiply both sides of your congruence by $16$ to obtain $x\equiv 16\times 53\pmod {69}$.